# "I (will) send the book on Monday so you (will) get it on Tuesday."

Tags: present-tense, future

my sentences:
**(1)** *I **will send** the book on Monday so you **will get** it on Tuesday*.
**(2)** *I **will send** the book on Monday so you **get** it on Tuesday*.
**(3)** *I **send** the book on Monday so you **will get** it on Tuesday*.
**(4)** *I **send** the book on Monday so you **get** it on Tuesday*.

I think they are all correct and mean the same but I'm not sure.
Could you tell me please which are correct and which are maybe not?

Comment: #3 and #4 don't really make sense because **I send** is the simple present, used to state general facts and truths, but not future plans.  The only way they would make sense is if you're saying you *always* send the book on Monday.

Comment: @stangdon "I fly to Paris on Wednesday."- it is a future plan. By analogy with it, using "I send" in (3) and (4) is correct too. Why am I not right? Thanks.

Comment: I agree that that is a clever observation and a good question.  The best explanation I can give is that we tend to use the "simple present for future" for things that are specifically scheduled like timetables or itineraries, like "My plane lands at six" or "We leave for England on the 22nd", but not for all planned actions in the future.  It's a subtle difference!

Comment: What @stangdon said. #3 and #4 are "valid", but not common except in somewhat contrived contexts it's not worth going into (especially #3, but #4 is okay if you send a book *every week*). It's entirely arbitrary whether you explicitly include ***will*** in the ***so-*** clause, but probably it's most common *not* to include it - and most native Anglophones who *did* include it would probably contract to ***...so you'll** get it [on] Tuesday*.

Comment: You may appreciate the answer I just gave to a similar question [HERE,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/340066/168419) providing an explanation of some of the principles about when to use "will" for future tenses.

Answer (score 0):

Use "will" and "will".

Simple present normally suggests general facts, not future events.  It's possible to say "I fly to Paris on Monday" when the future event is absolutely fixed by timetable (or to rhetorically emphasise that the event cannot be changed). That sense doesn't fit this context well (post dates don't normally follow a timetable)

The second part is a prediction of a future event.  "Will" or "going to" are possible, though "will" is more likely.  In both cases you'd contract the will to "'ll"

> I'll send it on Monday, so you'll get it on Tuesday.